# Centering 2D Shapes in Java

Tags: java, 2d, centering

I'm a novice programmer trying to overlay two 2D circles on top of each other. Each circle has different dimensions and I understand that adding or subrtracting from xCenter and yCenter will move the shape on an axis, but how do I know with certainty they are centered? Unfortunately I am a novice without many tools under my belt, so the simplest information possible would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RedCross extends JPanel
{
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(xCenter, yCenter, 40, 40);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(xCenter, yCenter, 10, 10);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Target");
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 200);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RedCross panel = new Target();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of an object is `window/2 - self/2` 
In code:

```
int xPanel = getWidth();
int yPanel = getHeight();

int sizeCircleOne = 40;
int sizeCircleTwo = 10;

// Drawing circle 1
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillOval(
 xPanel/2 - sizeCircleOne/2,
 yPanel/2 - sizeCircleOne/2,
 sizeCircleOne,
 sizeCircleOne
);

// Drawing circle 2
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(
 xPanel/2 - sizeCircleTwo/2,
 yPanel/2 - sizeCircleTwo/2,
 sizeCircleTwo,
 sizeCircleTwo
);
```

Let me know if it works.

Happy coding :) -Charlie

Answer (score 0):

The method you use to center your circles is how one should center objects. Just take a point on half of the width, and half of the height, and that's your center. This is because the center of a circle has all points on the circle equidistant from the center point. That's the definition of a circle.